# Equivalent to this Rest call, in JSOM or CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

```
/_api/web/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member,Member/Users,RoleDefinitionBindings
```

This line of code get you all the "members" with the users included aswell.

I cant seem to find anything similar in csom code, roledefinitionbinding:s member doesn't seem to have "users"?. Am I missing something? Or do I need to get users from sitegroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role Definitions are essentially permission levels.

If you want to see what users and groups have been *assigned* specific permission levels, you should look at an object's Role Assignments collection instead. Specifically, the Member property of a Role Assignment represents a user or group.

Here's an example of accessing the Role Assignments collection members using JavaScript:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var roleAssignments = clientContext.get_web().get_roleAssignments();
clientContext.load(roleAssignments,"Include(Member)");
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,
    function(){
        var roleAssignment, member, members = [],
          roleEnumerator = roleAssignments.getEnumerator();
        while(roleEnumerator.moveNext()){
            roleAssignment = roleEnumerator.get_current();
            member = roleAssignment.get_member();
            members.push({
                type:SP.Utilities.PrincipalType.toString(member.get_principalType()),
                login:member.get_loginName(),
                id:member.get_id(),
                name:member.get_title()
            });
        }
        alert(JSON.stringify(members));
    }),Function.createDelegate(this,
        function(sender,args){
                alert(args.get_message());
        })
);
```

You can dive down into the Site Groups collection to see the members of a specific group, once you have its ID.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am basicly trying to check if item/folder/site etc "HasCusomroleassignments", then get members. If loginname  contains #ext# its an external user. As you are suggesting i would need to take principalid when its a group and enumerate users via site groups.  And do The user check again. I was hoping to get the users from principalgroup ringt away like The rest example. But its fine 

Comment: I did a consoleapp that uses webclient for this REST call when sites, list, files and folders has custom roleassignments. It prints all external users and their items and permissions to a .csv.  but its a bit slow